# simultaneous login for admin and guest account

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I was trying to create a login page with codeigniter 3.1.7 version. I have two different login type i.e admin and guest but am checking the login attempt from the same login controller(User) to get accessed to my DB, but it doesn't login successfully even when I entered correct username and password, it always shows an error 'Wrong username or password provided'. Please check my code below:

User controller:

```
    public function login(){

    if($this->session->userdata('is_user_login')==TRUE){
        if($this->session->userdata('is_admin')==TRUE)
            redirect(base_url('admin/dashboard'),'');
        else
            redirect(base_url('guest/dashboard'),'');
        exit;
    }
    $data['title'] = 'Welcome';
    $data['msg'] = '';
    $signup_link = base_url('guest-signup');

    if(stristr($this->session->userdata('back_from_user_login'), 'admin/')){
        $signup_link = base_url('admin-signup');
    }
    else
    {
        $signup_link = base_url('guest-signup');
    }

    //$data['signup_link'] = $signup_link;

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $data['msg'] = $this->session->flashdata('msg');
        $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
        return;
    }

    $is_guest = TRUE;
    $folder = 'guest';
    $is_admin = FALSE;
    $userRow = $this->guest_model->authenticate_guest($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'));
    if(!$userRow){
        $is_guest = FALSE;
        $is_admin = TRUE;
        $folder = 'admin';
        $userRow = $this->admin_model->authenticate_admin($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'));
        if(!$userRow){
            $data['msg'] = 'Wrong username or password provided';
            $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
            return;
        }
    }

    if($userRow->sts=='pending'){
        $data['msg'] = 'You have not yet verified your username address.';
        $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
        return;
    }

    if($userRow->sts=='blocked'){
        $data['msg'] = 'Your account was suspended. Please contact site admin for further information.';
        $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
        return;
    }

    $user_data = array(
                            'id' => $userRow->ID,
                            'username' => $userRow->username,
             'is_user_login' => TRUE,
             'is_guest' => $is_guest,
             'is_admin' => $is_admin
             );
    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

    $this_model_name = ($is_admin==TRUE)?'admin_model':'guest_model';

    if($userRow->first_login_date==''){
        $this->$this_model_name->update($userRow->ID, array('first_login_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), 'last_login_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), 'sts' => 'active'));
    } else {
        $this->$this_model_name->update($userRow->ID, array('last_login_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));
    }

    $redirect = ($this->session->userdata('back_from_user_login')) ? $this->session->userdata('back_from_user_login') : $folder.'/dashboard';
    $this->session->set_userdata('back_from_user_login','');
    redirect(base_url($redirect), '');
}
```

admin_model.php :

```
    public function login(){

    if($this->session->userdata('is_user_login')==TRUE){
        if($this->session->userdata('is_admin')==TRUE)
            redirect(base_url('admin/dashboard'),'');
        else
            redirect(base_url('guest/dashboard'),'');
        exit;
    }
    $data['title'] = 'Welcome';
    $data['msg'] = '';
    $signup_link = base_url('guest-signup');

    if(stristr($this->session->userdata('back_from_user_login'), 'admin/')){
        $signup_link = base_url('admin-signup');
    }
    else
    {
        $signup_link = base_url('guest-signup');
    }

    //$data['signup_link'] = $signup_link;

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $data['msg'] = $this->session->flashdata('msg');
        $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
        return;
    }

    $is_guest = TRUE;
    $folder = 'guest';
    $is_admin = FALSE;
    $userRow = $this->guest_model->authenticate_guest($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'));
    if(!$userRow){
        $is_guest = FALSE;
        $is_admin = TRUE;
        $folder = 'admin';
        $userRow = $this->admin_model->authenticate_admin($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'));
        if(!$userRow){
            $data['msg'] = 'Wrong username or password provided';
            $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
            return;
        }
    }

    if($userRow->sts=='pending'){
        $data['msg'] = 'You have not yet verified your username address.';
        $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
        return;
    }

    if($userRow->sts=='blocked'){
        $data['msg'] = 'Your account was suspended. Please contact site admin for further information.';
        $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
        return;
    }

    $user_data = array(
                            'id' => $userRow->ID,
                            'username' => $userRow->username,
             'is_user_login' => TRUE,
             'is_guest' => $is_guest,
             'is_admin' => $is_admin
             );
    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

    $this_model_name = ($is_admin==TRUE)?'admin_model':'guest_model';

    if($userRow->first_login_date==''){
        $this->$this_model_name->update($userRow->ID, array('first_login_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), 'last_login_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), 'sts' => 'active'));
    } else {
        $this->$this_model_name->update($userRow->ID, array('last_login_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));
    }

    $redirect = ($this->session->userdata('back_from_user_login')) ? $this->session->userdata('back_from_user_login') : $folder.'/dashboard';
    $this->session->set_userdata('back_from_user_login','');
    redirect(base_url($redirect), '');
}
```

guest_model.php

```
 public function authenticate_guest($user_name, $password) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('guests');
    $this->db->where('username', $user_name);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->row();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}
```

loing_view

```
<div class="login-form">
    <?php if($msg):?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo $msg;?></div>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success_msg');?>
    <form method="post" name="login_form" id="login_form" action="">
<li>
<input type="text" class="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" placeholder="Username" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
    </li>
<li>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" placeholder="Password">
</li>
<input type="submit" value="SIGN IN" >
    </form>
    </div>
```

your help is highly appreciated...

Comment: add relevant code only. not entire code. Its hard to read even

Comment: You will probably have to create separate user systems for them, otherwise you will wind up overriding your Session data.  Create one system for `user` and one for `admin` and make sure to prefix anything you save in the session that you dont want over written.  So you may do `user_id` and `admin_id` but not `id` for both of them.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to be able to login as a user and as an admin at the same time? That's... strange... Typically both users should be able to login through the same controller, then just cross reference their group for certain permissions based on their permission level. Flow ex user logins in > get user group > redirect to admin or user page based on that. User tries to access admin page, can't because they don't have that permission.

Comment: hi guys thanks for your help plzcheck my simplified code below and help me identify the problem:                                    
$userRow = $this->guest_model->authenticate_guest($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'));
  if(!$userRow){
   $is_guest = FALSE;
   $is_admin = TRUE;
   $folder = 'admin';
   $userRow = $this->admin_model->authenticate_admin($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'));
   if(!$userRow){
    $data['msg'] = 'Wrong username or password provided';
    $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
    return;
   }
  }